# Сделать из строки набор ссылок с помощью регулярок JS

Tags: javascript, html

Возможно вопрос не серьезный, но я уже переломал всю голову. Может кто то даст идею.

**Вопрос:** Есть строка типа: "Субботы по Богоявлении: Еф. 6:10–17 (зач. 233). Мф. 4:1–11 (зач. 7). Ряд.: Кол. 1:3–6 (зач. 249 от полу). Лк. 16:10–15 (зач. 81)."

Каждая ее структурная часть выглядит так "Еф. 6:10–17 (зач. 233)." или так "Мф. 4:25 – 5:12."

Реально ли из этой строки сделать динамическую ссылку типа `<a href="/?Mk.12:1-12" target="_blank">Мк. 12:1–12</a>` из **Мк. 12:1–12 (зач 33)** или как то похоже? Чтобы каждый эллемент имел ссылку передающую ее динамическое значение. Спасибо.

**Пытаюсь объяснить более понятно:**

Каждая ссылка, как и данные, начинается с букв. Есть их массив: 
`Arr = ['Гал.','Деян.','Евр.','Еф.','Иак.'','Кол.','1 Кор.','2 Кор.','Лк.','Мк.','Мф.','Откр.','1 Пет.','1 Пет.','2 Пет.','Рим.','1 Сол.','2 Сол.','1 Тим.','2 Тим.','Тит.','Флм.','Флп.'];` - это и есть начало данных, заканчивается это на ")." То есть "в Еф. 6:10–17 (зач. 233)." 
Начало данных Eф, заканчивается на ). Внутри 6: это глава, 10-17 - это параграфы. Из этого нужно сделать что то типа Ef6_10-17, (зач. 233) не нужен. По итогу Еф. 6:10–17 (зач. 233) сделать ссылкой на ?Ef6_10-17. Надеюсь я понятно объяснил )))

Пытался интегрировать ваш скрипт со своим, что то не выходит. Может вы подскажите что я делаю не так? Вот последняя версия скрипта :

```js
  "use strict";
  let str = document.getElementById('eva').innerText;
  let arrT = ['Гал','Деян','Евр','Еф','Иак','Ин','1 Ин','2 Ин','3 Ин','Иуд','Кол','1 Кор','2 Кор','Лк','Мк','Мф','Откр','1 Пет','2 Пет','Рим','1 Сол','2 Сол','1 Тим','2 Тим','Тит','Флм','Флп', 'Гал','Деян','Евр','Еф','Иак','Ин','1 Ин','2 Ин','3 Ин','Иуд','Кол','1 Кор','2 Кор','Лк','Мк','Мф','Откр','1 Пет','2 Пет','Рим','1 Сол','2 Сол','1 Тим','2 Тим','Тит','Флм','Флп'];
     
  let newStr = setLinks(str, arrT);
  
document.getElementById("eva").innerHTML = newStr;
  
  function setLinks(str, keysW) {
    for (let i = 0; i < keysW.length; i++) {
      let el = keysW[i];
      if (!str.includes(el)) continue;
      let textLink = new RegExp(`${el}.*?\\)`).exec(str)[0];
      let evaType = rReplaceSymb( textLink.slice(0, textLink.indexOf(".")) );
      
      // -------------------Генерация якорной ссыоки--------------------------
      let ancore ;
      let tire;
      if (textLink.indexOf('–') > 0 ){ tire = '–';}else{tire = '-';}

        let st = textLink.slice(0, textLink.indexOf(tire)).split(".")[1].split(":")[1];
        if (st > 2){st = st-2;}
        ancore = ('#row_' + textLink.slice(0, textLink.indexOf(tire)).split(".")[1].split(":")[0].replace(/[\s\ ]/g, "")) + '_' + st;
     
    
    
    
      //--------------------------Генерация ссылки-------------------
      let typeDotes = textLink.slice(0, textLink.indexOf("(")).match(/\:/g).length;
      let link;

      if (typeDotes == 1){
        
          link = textLink
          .slice(0, textLink.indexOf("("))
          .split(".")[1]
          .replace(/[\s\.]/g, "")
          .replace(/\:/, "&st=")
          .split("")
          .join("");

      }else if(typeDotes == 2){
       
        let start = textLink
          .slice(0, textLink.indexOf(tire))
          .split(".")[1]
          .replace(/[\s\.]/g, "")
          .replace(/\:/, "&st=")
          .split("")
          .join("") + '-200';

          let end = textLink
          .slice(0, textLink.indexOf('('))
          .split(tire)[1]
          .replace(/\:/, "&st2=1-")
          .replace(/[\s\ ]/g, "")
          end  = '&gl2=' + end;
          console.log(end);

          link = start + end;

      }
      
 

      
      str = str.replace(textLink, `<a href='${evaType}?gl=${link}${ancore}' target='_blank'>${textLink}</a>`);
    }

    return str;
  
  }
  
  function rReplaceSymb(str) {
    
    let res;
    switch(str){

      case 'Гал' : res = '/evangelie/poslanie-k-galatam'; break;
      case 'Деян' : res = '/evangelie/deyaniya-apostolov'; break;
      case 'Евр' : res = '/evangelie/poslanie-k-evreyam'; break;
      case 'Еф' : res = '/evangelie/poslanie-k-efesyanam'; break;
      case 'Иак' : res = '/evangelie/poslanie-iakova'; break;
      case 'Ин' : res = '/evangelie/ot-ioanna'; break;
      case '1 Ин' : res = '/evangelie/pervoe-poslanie-ioanna'; break;
      case '2 Ин' : res = '/evangelie/vtoroe-poslanie-ioanna'; break;
      case '3 Ин' : res = '/evangelie/trete-poslanie-ioanna'; break;
      case 'Иуд' : res = '/evangelie/poslanie-iudy'; break;
      case 'Кол' : res = '/evangelie/poslanie-k-kolossyanam'; break;
      case '1 Кор' : res = '/evangelie/pervoe-poslanie-k-korinfyanam'; break;
      case '2 Кор' : res = '/evangelie/vtoroe-poslanie-k-korinfyanam'; break;
      case 'Лк' : res = '/evangelie/ot-luki'; break;
      case 'Мк' : res = '/evangelie/ot-marka'; break;
      case 'Мф' : res = '/evangelie/ot-matfeya'; break;
      case 'Откр' : res = '/evangelie/otkrovenie-ioanna-bogoslova'; break;
      case '1 Пет' : res = '/evangelie/pervoe-poslanie-petra'; break;
      case '2 Пет' : res = '/evangelie/vtoroe-poslanie-petra'; break;
      case 'Рим' : res = '/evangelie/poslanie-k-rimlyanam'; break;
      case '1 Сол' : res = '/evangelie/1-e-poslanie-k-fessalonikijcam'; break;
      case '2 Сол' : res = '/evangelie/2-e-poslanie-k-fessalonikijcam'; break;
      case '1 Тим' : res = '/evangelie/pervoe-poslanie-k-timofeyu'; break;
      case '2 Тим' : res = '/evangelie/vtoroe-poslanie-k-timofeyu'; break;
      case 'Тит' : res = '/evangelie/poslanie-k-titu'; break;
      case 'Флм' : res = '/evangelie/poslanie-k-filimonu'; break;
      case 'Флп' : res = '/evangelie/poslanie-k-filippijcam'; break;

      default: res = str;

    }

      return res;

  }
```

Comment: Возможно, с помощью регулярных выражений. Вы приведите больше примеров с входными и выходными данными.

Comment: правь вопрос___

Comment: Да, добавьте эту информацию в вопрос. Под вопросом есть кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1072915/edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
"use strict";
let str = "Субботы по Богоявлении: Еф. 6:10–17 (зач. 233). Мф. 4:1–11 (зач. 7). Еф. 7:10–17 (зач. 233). Ряд.: Кол. 1:3–6 (зач. 249 от полу). Лк. 16:10–15 (зач. 81).";
let arrT = ["Еф", 'Лк', 'Мф'];
let newStr = setLinks(str, arrT);
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = newStr;

function editLink(textLink) {
  return textLink.slice(0, textLink.indexOf("("))
     .replace(/[\s\.]/g, "")
     .replace(/\:/g, "_")
     .split("")
     .map(rReplaceSymb)
     .join("");
}

function setLinks(str, keysW) {
  for (let i = 0; i < keysW.length; i++) {
    let el = keysW[i];
    if (!str.includes(el)) continue;
    let textLinks = str.match(new RegExp(`\\B${el}.*?\\)`, "g"));
    let links = textLinks.map(editLink);
    for (let j = 0; j < textLinks.length; j++) {
      str = str.replace(textLinks[j], `<a href='/?${links[j]}' target='_blank'>${textLinks[j]}</a>`);
    }
  }
  return str;
}

function rReplaceSymb(str) {
  const mappedSymbols = {
    'E': 'E',
    'е': 'e',
    'ф': 'f',
    'К': 'K',
    'к': 'k',
    'о': 'o',
    'Л': 'L',
    'l': 'l'
  };
  return mappedSymbols[str] ? mappedSymbols[str] : str;
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Вариант оочень хороший. Единственное идет жесткая привязка `let arrT = ['Еф', 'Мф', "Лк"];` если порядок не тот(а он каждый раз разный) выдает "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
    at 24:798"

Comment: @Павел
 исправил.

Comment: Большое спасибо  fixeri, работает все как надо. Браво!

Comment: А не могли бы вы прислать строчки, которые исправили, я просто переделал скрипт до неузнаваемости, либо я могу сбросить свой скрипт. Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

В общем виде можно сделать вот так. Надо еще доработать функцию `cyrylicToLatin`, но мне лень.

```js
const text = "Субботы по Богоявлении: Еф. 6:10–17 (зач. 233). Мф. 4:1–11 (зач. 7). Ряд.: Кол. 1:3–6 (зач. 249 от полу). Лк. 16:10–15 (зач. 81). Еф. 7:10–17 (зач. 233).";

function cyrylicToLatin(word) {
  let result = "";
  // Надо сделать со всеми символами, но мне лень.
  const mappedSymbols = {
    'E': 'E',
    'е': 'e',
    'ф': 'f',
    'К': 'K',
    'к': 'k',
    'о': 'o',
    'л': 'l'
  };
  for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    const symb = word[i];
    const mappedSymb = mappedSymbols[symb];
    if (mappedSymb !== undefined) {
      result += mappedSymb;
    } else {
      result += symb;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

function getUrls(message) {
  const words = ['Гал.', 'Деян.', 'Евр.', 'Еф.', 'Иак.', 'Кол.', '1 Кор.', '2 Кор.', 'Лк.', 'Мк.', 'Мф.', 'Откр.', '1 Пет.', '1 Пет.', '2 Пет.', 'Рим.', '1 Сол.', '2 Сол.', '1 Тим.', '2 Тим.', 'Тит.', 'Флм.', 'Флп.'];
  const result = [];
  words.forEach(word => {
    const regex = new RegExp(`(${word})\\s*(\\d+:)(\\d+(–|-)\\d+)`, 'ig');
    let res = regex.exec(message);
    while (res) {
      const name = cyrylicToLatin(res[1].replace('.', ''));
      const paragraph = res[2].replace(':', '_');
      const pages = res[3];
      result.push(name + paragraph + pages);
      res = regex.exec(message);
    }
  });
  return result;
}

const urls = getUrls(text);
console.log(urls);
```

Comment: Работает отлично. Подумал что нет смысла в в латиницу переводить и решил не использовать первую функцию. Хотел Попросить еще с RegExp. Вы написали фильтр для типа **Мк. 12:1–12** "RegExp(`(${word})\\s*(\\d+:)(\\d+(–|-)\\d+)`, 'ig');". Не могли бы вы помочь со строчкой RegExp для типа **Мк. 12:1–13, 16-17** а так же **Мк. 12:1–13:3** а так же **Мк. 12:1–13, 13:16-17**. Просто регулярку бы. А я обещаю выучить эту тему. )

Comment: @Павел вы лучше приведите примеры данных в вопросе, как я и просил в своем первом комментарии. Примеры всех возможных входных данных и во что они должны преобразоваться.

Comment: Степан, большое вам спасибо за помощь. Скрипт от  fixeri работает отлично. Ваш тоже очень хороший. Спасибо за выделенное время!

Comment: @Павел в его ответе есть неточность. Например, если строка будет такая *Субботы по Богоявлении: Еф. 6:10–17 (зач. 233). Мф. 4:1–11 (зач. 7). Еф. 7:10–17 (зач. 233). Ряд.: Кол. 1:3–6 (зач. 249 от полу). Лк. 16:10–15 (зач. 81).*, т.е. два одинаковых слова, например  Еф., то второй не будет работать.

Comment: Ну в данном случае это не важно, так как на одной странице, но если вы знаете фикс, был бы благодарен. )))

Comment: @Павел проверьте мой ответ, отредактировал - исправил.)

Comment: @fixeri все еще при повторе не подсвечивает. Тестируйте на строке *Субботы по Богоявлении: Еф. 6:10–17 (зач. 233). Мф. 4:1–11 (зач. 7). Еф. 7:10–17 (зач. 233). Ряд.: Кол. 1:3–6 (зач. 249 от полу). Лк. 16:10–15 (зач. 81).*

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko протестировал на вашей строке.
с Вводными данными let arrT = ['Мф', 'Лк', 'Еф']; все работает.

Comment: @fixeri действительно, теперь работает! +1

Comment: А не могли бы вы прислать строчки, которые исправили, я просто переделал скрипт до неузнаваемости, либо я могу сбросить свой скрипт. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @Павел вы не тому написали. fixeri  не увидит ваш коммент.

Comment: Еще тут новечек, сейчас еще попробую ) Спасибо!)